# Выполнение php скрипта по расписанию без CRON

Tags: cron, php

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста решить задачу, на сайте есть еженедельный конкурс, каждый понедельник в 0:00 он должен начинаться, а каждое воскресенье в 23:59(или если возможно в 0:00), завершаться, и сразу после начисления приза начинался опять? Но вот как запускать php скрипт каждый понедельник в 0:00 без CRON, я не знаю... Подскажите пожалуйста решение проблемы.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[cron online](http://mywebcron.com/), указываете ссылку на файл на своем ресурсе, который надо дергать в нужное время, ну и указываете время.

Comment: ого, спасибо за ресурс!

Comment: хотел попробовать у меня выходить ошибка: Some thing gone wrong! General error.

Answer (score 1):

пробовал выше указанный ресурс(http://mywebcron.com), там выдал ошибку `Some thing gone wrong! General error`. нашел вот эту:
https://www.easycron.com вроде этот все отработал супер!
также есть еще один https://crondash.com