# Запись данных сразу в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, синтаксический-анализ

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать так, что бы не заходя на сайт данные записывались в БД.
Т.е. есть прарсер данных с одного сайта. Вот хотелось бы, чтобы можно было полученные данных записывались сразу в БД. Как это можно реализовать? 
(Я новичок)

Comment: А может стоит начать с изучения русского языка? Ты действительно уверен что новичек пишется именно так "навечек"? Я очень сожалею о твоем уровне образования. Зачем изучать языки программирования, если родно язык еще не изучен?

Comment: > если родно язык
Иронично =)

Answer (score 1):

Если на сервере нет крона, то используйте крон [крон онлайн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/250615/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-php-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-cron)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте cron. Вызывайте PHP-скрипт с помощью планировщика задач в определенное время.